# iTunes grayed-out menu

Tags: itunes

I know this is not a new problem, but I haven't seen a solution to it so I figured I'd go ahead and see if anyone has come across a solution here:

Sometimes iTunes grays out menu bar options such as Quit iTunes and Add to Library. I never noticed any pattern about when this happens, but I've read that others experience it after editing tracks in their libraries. I've also checked for open dialog boxes somewhere, but I don't have any of those.

Anyone know why this is still happening (years after I first saw this), and if there is any solution yet? I am on OS X 10.7.5 and running whatever version of iTunes is the latest that is available via Software Update (the About iTunes option is grayed out as well so I can't check that right now). Any ideas would be much appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One year later, this is happening to me as well. I'm on 10.8.5 and iTunes 11. I have used iTunes since it's inception and don't think I've had this problem until iTunes 11.

Most menu items are greyed out, like Quit and Preferences, but some work, like new Playlist and most items under the File menu. Otherwise iTunes still works, but to quit, I have to force quit or close down the Mac altogether. I see no open dialog boxes anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please resist the urge to post comments in the answer field! New users don't have comment privileges, which I know is frustrating, but if you just want a way to stay on top of this question mark it as a favorite.

Comment: Although it's a bit buried, the answer here is that iTunes can get stuck and force quit is the solution.

Comment: @bmike if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. That's the only thing that ever worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, several Apple programs seem to do some cleanup that can get hung after you tell the program to quit. Mail and iTunes seems to be several I've dealt with on multiple occasions with multiple versions of the OS.

In each case, force quitting the application is the only practical response.

- [OS X: How to quit an unresponsive application using Force Quit - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3411](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3411)

  1. Choose force quit from the Apple Menu
  2. Select and quit iTunes

Should you run into this on an ongoing basis, you'll need to try rebuilding the database file for iTunes or restore it from a backup before the issue started.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to Preferences → Advanced → Reset warnings. It fixed the problem for me on a Mac.